# R - remove anything after number from string

Tags: php

How to remove name after four digits number,always my alphabets starts after 4 digit number,

suppose my string names are

```
2015 ABC
2016 XYZ
2015 ABCD
ABC 2015 BOS
```

Here I want to remove `ABC,XYZ,ABCD,BOS`

I want to print only  like

```
  2015
  2015
  2015 
  ABC 2015
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to do that.

There are loads of online material, tutorials and even testers that can help you out.

Just Google *"regular expressions"*.

Here is a really simple example that will do what you want:

```
$string = 'ABC 2015 BOS';
$newString = preg_replace('/([0-9]+) [A-Za-z ]+/','$1',$string);
```

Comment: The regexp above is trying to find the pattern within the searchable string. It will replace that pattern (if found) with the second argument in the preg_replace function. The $1 is the first part of the regexp in brackets - ([0-9]+). So what the above regexp is saying is find any pattern that is a number followed by a space followed by a string of letters and replace it with the number found. Please read up on the function as well http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this: checked for all the egs you've listed above

```
preg_replace('/\s+([\S]*)$/', '', $string)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are sure that words are separated by space, you could use explode() to cut your string to words, then remove the last and implode().

```
<?php

$lines = [
"2015 ABC",
"2016 XYZ",
"2015 ABCD",
"ABC 2015 BOS"];

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $words = explode(" ", $line);
    unset($words[count($words) -1]);

    $filtered = implode($words, " ");
    print($filtered. "\n");
}
```

The previous code will print exactly as you asked:

```
2015
2016
2015
ABC 2015
```